# DataTable.load not working

Tags: .net, oracle, datatable, ado.net

I am trying to load a datatable using the following code.

```
OracleDataReader AssignedReader = AssignedCommand.ExecuteReader();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(AssignedReader);
```

Prior to dt.Load, AssignedReader.HasRows is set to true. 
After dt.Load, dt has 0 rows. However if I do the following:

```
while (AssignedReader.Read())
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

It returns rows. Its like all the rows decide to vanish the moment I try to put it in a DataTable and I can't figure out how to make it work. I have done this 1000 times before and have never had this problem. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hi Michael, I am currently experiencing this exact issue, did you ever manage to fix it? The records are there in the reader when ExecuteReader is called, however when dt.Load is called they seem to disappear!

Comment: Nope. I never figured out what the problem was. I ended up having to just not implement that feature as a result of this.

Comment: Well I don't know if it'll help now but for me it turned out to be an entirely unrelated issue, and in fact the DataTable.load does actually load the records into it (as you can observe by looking at the count field on DataTable) but for some reason visual studio debugger shows what appears to be an empty table. When I actually attempted to do something with the contents of DataTable, it did in fact contain all the data.

Comment: @JustinMoser is correct. I had the same issue. After calling `dataTable.Rows.Count` also the data appeared. Must be an initialisation problem somehow?